# Deploy App Engine from Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Im using android studio to add a backend to an android app but when i try to deploy using this command in the terminal

```
gradlew appengineUpdate
```

fails with this error

```
-------------- REQUEST  --------------                   
POST https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/generate/res
t
Accept-Encoding: gzip                                    
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.18.0-rc-SNAPSHOT (gzip)
Content-Type: application/json                           
Content-Length: 2093                                     

curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HT
TP-Java-Client/1.18.0-rc-SNAPSHOT (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d
'@-' -- 'https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/generate
/rest' << $$$
Done running endpoints command get-client-lib            
:backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs FAILED          
:backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 2.
719 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: webapis-discovery.
appspot.com   

* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to g
et more log output.

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 15.452 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s)
```

Im using Android Studio 0.5.7 and following this guide
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

any idea what could be my problem?

Ive being googleing for 3 days and havent found anything about it

running with --stacktrace:

```
gradlew appengineUpdate --stacktrace
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:backend:appengineDownloadSdk                                                                                              
:backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                  
:backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE      
:backend:classes UP-TO-DATE      
:backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs FAILED                                                      

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: webapis-discovery.appspot.com

* Try:        
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: webapis-discovery.appspot.com
        at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask.runEndpointsCommand(EndpointsTask.groovy:47)
        at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask$runEndpointsCommand.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.GetClientLibsTask.executeTask(GetClientLibsTask.groovy:39)
        at com.google.appengine.task.AbstractTask.start(AbstractTask.groovy:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: webapis-discovery.appspot.com
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.postRequest(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:75)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.generateDiscoveryDoc(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:56)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenDiscoveryDocAction.genDiscoveryDoc(GenDiscoveryDocAction.java:105)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.getClientLib(GetClientLibAction.java:79)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.execute(GetClientLibAction.java:55)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:68)
        at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask.runEndpointsCommand(EndpointsTask.groovy:44)
        ... 63 more


BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 15.581 secs
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, maybe naming or endpoint declaration. Can you add your code? Or trace it down by removing methods.

Comment: I havent even added code of my own, i'm testing the code generated by the template, its just one entity and one endpoint, i'm just following the guide in the github repo linked above, and there are not errors in the code since it builds and run fine locally if you check the guide the failing step is the 2.2 part everything else before that runs fine

Comment: can you run it with --stacktrace to see what the error is?

Comment: added the output of --stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I have been experiencing this problem with Android Studios v1 and it seems to pop up occasionally when I modify the gradle file for my backend - don't know why. I usually restart my Android Studios and then gradle builds it successfully after the restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally made it to work, I was missing the name of the app in my case "backend" the command was

```
gradlew :backend:appengineUpdate
```

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio itself showed a red X over my backend project, I followed what BradR said and terminal prompted that gradlew did not exist as a command, so if that doesn't work for you, then try this:

```
./gradlew :backendName:appengineRun
```